# Retornar dados do Cliente

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, .net-core

Bom dia Pessoal,

Gostaria de criar uma função, que retornasse o cliente solicitado, e seus dados, que estão em 3 tabelas diferentes `Clientes`, `ClientesTelephone`, `ClientesEmail`, consigo adicionar o cliente perfeitamente com minha função `CreateClientAsync`.

CreateClientAsync:

```
public async Task<ApplicationClient> CreateClientAsync(ApplicationClient client)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _context.Clientes.AddAsync(client);

            if (result.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }

            return result.Entity;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

estou tentando desenvolver uma função para retornar os dados do cliente, chamada `GetClientAsync`, mas não sei por onde começar, poderiam me ajudar por favor ?

```
public async Task<ApplicationClient> GetClientAsync(ApplicationClient client)
    {
        try
        {


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Tabela `Clientes`:

```
public class ApplicationClient
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TipoPessoa { get; set; }

    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public Guid UsuarioId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationClientTelephone> ClientesTelefone { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationClientEmail> ClientesEmail { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UsuarioId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Usuario { get; set; }

}`
```

Tabelas `ClientesEmail`:

```
public class ApplicationClientEmail
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public String Email { get; set; }

    public Guid ClienteId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClienteId")]
    public virtual ApplicationClient Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

Tabelas `ClientesTelefone`:

```
public class ApplicationClientTelephone
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public String Telefone { get; set; }

    public Guid ClienteId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClienteId")]
    public virtual ApplicationClient Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve usar o **Include** (Join do EF) caso a opção **LazyLoading** estiver definido como falso, senão ele fará automaticamente os Joins.

Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
var result = await _context.Clientes.Include("ClientEmail").Include("ClientTelephone").FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
```

Recomendo usar *FirstOrDefault* para não gerar exceção se o elemento não existir, apenas retornará nulo, mais sobre: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq

Comment: Estou recebendo o erro que 'ApplicationClient' não contém uma definição para 'GetAwaiter'

Comment: Desculpe, troque o _FirstOrDefault_ por *FirstOrDefaultAsync*

Comment: Estou usando essa função para verificar se o `CNPJ `ou `CPF `, já está inserido na tabela, então pelo oque entendi, caso ele não encontre ele retornará `null`, e a partir desse `null` consigo fazer um `if` e fazer essa verificação, correto ?

Comment: Isso! exatamente, você ira testar se o objeto Cliente é diferente de nulo e tratar, if(cliente != null) { // Achou!  } else { //Não achou }

Comment: No caso eu não consigo retornar a `var` `result`, pois recebo o seguinte erro:  `Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "EasySistema.Models.ApplicationClient em Microsoft.Asp.NetCore.Mvc.ActionResult`